# Issue with Chart Winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linechart

I am drawing a line chart but the issue is it is not making data points as described in chart properties it just breaks line (a small white space) and move ahead to draw the remaining line .Chart and code attached.

[image: Line Chart]

Here is the code:

```
            var series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series.Points.DataBind(dv1, "DateCreated", "Visibility", "");
            chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
            chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = 100;
            chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.Series[0].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
            chart1.SaveImage(pdfFile, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

What am i missing here ?

**UPDATE:**

Dv1 is basically :

```
Visibility       DateCreated
  10              2017-10-21
  20              2017-10-22
  30              2017-10-23
  45              2017-10-24
  90              2017-10-25
```

I am trying to make graph as below :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What are the properties that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado should there not be a diamond at the white spaces ?

Comment: @MartinBackasch see update please

Comment: Try `series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;`

Comment: @LarsTech thanx it worked :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, your code is referencing the wrong "series" in the chart control.  Instead of this:

```
chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
```

it should reference the series variable you created:

```
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
```